# WebdriverIO - Convert HTML to PNG

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, webpage-screenshot

I trying to convert html to png using webdriverIO but it's not working.
Kindly help me out.

```
var selenium = require('selenium-standalone' 5.6.2);

var wdioScreenshot = require('wdio-screenshot' 0.2.1);

var webdriverio = require('webdriverio' 4.2.11).remote(
        options
    );
    
    wdioScreenshot.init(webdriverio);

    webdriverio
        .init()
        .url('http://www.google.com')
        .saveScreenshot('google.png')
        .end()
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("title error===============>"+err);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that worked

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .saveScreenshot('google.png')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end()
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```